# A problem when add Library in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

i try to add ZipArchive folder that contain source code, then drag and drop to my project

when i try to include

```
#import "ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h"
```

why it report error: ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h: No such file or directory

if i import

```
#import "ZipArchive.h"
```

it will work, what is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a folder to your project, it will ask you to add a folder reference or a group. If you add a group, everything will be put at the top level of your application bundle. But if you use a folder reference, it will actually be in the folder, and you can use `ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h`.

[image: refs]